# setting the width of a bar wit h an object propriety

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I am trying to set the width of a bar to be whatever I get from a fetch, but I get the following message: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'width')"

I don't really understand why I get this message as I have defined the width with css  to be 100%:

```
.peg-1-bar-fill, .peg-2-bar-fill, .peg-3-bar-fill, .peg-4-bar-fill, .peg-5-bar-fill, .peg-6-bar-fill, .peg-7-bar-fill, .peg-8-bar-fill, .peg-9-bar-fill, .peg-10-bar-fill,
.peg-11-bar-fill, .peg-12-bar-fill {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
```

and here is the html:

```
<div class="peg-wrapper">
        <div class="peg-name-7">
          <h4>7</h4>
        </div>
        <p class="label-3">Starts:</p>
        <span class="time-start-peg-7"></span>
        <p class="label-1">Ends:</p>
        <span id="time-end-peg-7"></span>
        <div class="peg-7-start-time total-time">
          <p class="label-2">Length:</p>
          <span id="total-time-7"></span>
          <span id="peg-7-update-time">+10</span>

        </div>
        <div class="peg-7-bar">
          <div class="peg-7-bar-fill">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="peg-7-timer">
          <span id="time-peg-7"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and the JS:

```
const pegsData_url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";
const uiProgressBarPeg7 = document.getElementsByClassName(`peg-1-bar-fill`);
const pegs1 = document.getElementById("total-time-1");
const max = 100;
fetch(pegsData_url)
  .then((data) => {
    return data.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data);
  })
  .then((completedata) => {
    console.log(completedata);

const   peg7 = {
      status: completedata[1].id,
      startTime: completedata[7].price,
      endTime: completedata[7].price,
      totalLength: completedata[7].price+'m',
      remainingTime: completedata[7].price+'m',
      barPercentage:completedata[9].price,
    };
    console.log(peg7.barPercentage);
    const percent = (peg7.barPercentage) / max * 100;// it shoul be 109
    console.log(percent);
    uiProgressBarPeg7.style.width = `${percent}%`;


    if( peg7.status === 0){
      uiProgressBarPeg7.style.background = "var(--color-light-gray)";
      }
      else if ( peg7.status === 1) {
        uiProgressBarPeg7.style.background = "var(--dark-green-color)";
      } else if ( peg7.status === 2) {
    //     uiProgressBarPeg7.style.background = "var(--light-orange-color)";
      }
      else if(peg7.status === 3){
        uiProgressBarPeg7.style.background = "var(--light-red-color)";
        uiTime.style.fontFamily = 'Poppins, sans-serif';
        uiTime.style.fontSize = '16px';
      }
      else if (peg7.status === 4){
        uiProgressBarPeg7.style.background = "var(--color-light-gray)";
      }
      if( peg7.status== 0 & peg7.barPercentage ===0 ){
        uiProgressBarPeg7.style.background = "var(--color-light-gray)";

      }//continue from here


    document.getElementsByClassName("time-start-peg-7").innerHTML = peg2.startTime;
    document.getElementById("time-end-peg-7").innerHTML = peg2.startTime;
    document.getElementById("total-time-7").innerHTML = peg2.totalLength;
    document.getElementById("time-peg-7").innerHTML = peg2.totalLength;

}
```

after setting the width, it should also change the color of the bar, It works on the following example:

```
let max = 100;
    let barPercentagePeg1 = 5;
    let status=2 ;

const percent = (barPercentagePeg1 / max) * 100;
      uiProgressBar.style.width = `${percent}%`;//here

      if (status === 1) {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "var(--dark-green-color)";
      } else if (status === 2) {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "var(--light-orange-color)";
      } else if (status === 3) {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "var(--light-red-color)";
      }else if(status === 0) {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "var(--color-light-gray)";
      }
```

any suggestions/ help, please?

Comment: Look at how you are setting uiProgressBar - there is nothing in your HTML with class peg-1-bar-fill so uiProgessBar is null and so you can't find a width. Is this just a typo (1 instead of 7) or is there something else? You can use your browser's dev tools inspect facility console to find such errors.

Comment: @ A Haworth thanks for your feedback, there are 11 more pegs, each of one the same proprieties with different values. as I am testing it, it doesn't have to be on a specific value, it just has to work, but it still gives me the same error, is there something am I missing?

Comment: Put some debugging into your code - use console.log to check the actual values that are being produced/used at each stage to track down where things are going wrong.

Comment: The most important thing here is "*Cannot set properties of undefined*". This error is telling you that you have something that is undefined (and for an element, this means the element does not exist), and you are trying to set a property (*width*) for that undefined thing. And so, if it doesn't exist, you cannot set any properties for it. And usually there will be a line number with the error telling you where in your code it is doing this. From there you can look to see where that variable gets set to see why it is undefined (*typo, setting variable before element is loaded/ready, etc.*)